# Deleting specific rows/columns from excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to delete specific rows from Microsoft excel. My data set has around 900,000 rows, I want to get ride of rows/columns that are for example, from b325890-b500000 without dragging my mouse down and clearing it. How would I do this? **I am using Excel 2011 on A Mac.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I delete a range of rows using VBA?

> **Excel VBA Examples for Deleting multiple Rows at time**
>
> The following example will delete Row 5 to 10 at a time from the
>   active worksheet.
>
> ```
> 'In this Example I am deleting Rows 5 to 10
> Sub sbDeleteARowMulti()
>
> Rows("5:10").Delete
>
> End Sub
> ```
>
> **Instructions**
>
> 1. Open an Excel Workbook
> 2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA Editor
> 3. Insert a Module from Insert Menu
> 4. Copy the above code and Paste in the code window
> 5. Save the file as macro enabled workbook
> 6. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute it

Source [Delete Rows and Columns in Excel VBA](http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/delete-rows-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

You may also like to try the Go To function. Very simple: on your mac, press CTRL+G (control, not command) and the Go To dialog will open.

Do you want to delete the entire rows between 325890-500000? If so enter **325890:500000** and click OK. Excel will select the rows, and you can right-click on any of the row numbers on the left, and delete, or clear contents.

Or do you want to delete only within column **B** across those rows? If so enter **b325890:b500000** and click OK. Excel selects those cells and you can delete (and shift cells) or clear contents.