# How to delete rows in excel based on column values based on a column where values are repeating?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to delete rows in my excel sheet based on a column where values are repeating.

[image: Excel Sheet with repeated column values]

Now in the above image I want to remove rows 3,4,5,7,8,9,10 as it has values repeating in column A. This is a small example , but the actual data contains thousands of rows. Can anyone let me know if there any logical formula I can  apply.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: There is no Logical formula to delete rows.
You will have to use vba such as [this](http://superuser.com/questions/997804/deleting-specific-rows-columns-from-excel/997808)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Remove Duplicates** under **Data Tab** in Excel.
First sort your data to make the row that contains all the data is the first in the duplicate, for example: Name (A to Z), Address (Z to A), Age (largest to smallest) or if your data is the same as shown above it is ok.
Select all your data and click on Remove Duplicates (My Data has Headers should be selected) and choose only Name column and Ok.