# Select & delete first n rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of thousands of different values. I would like to delete something like the first 85,000 values.

Is there a less tedious way to do this other than clicking and dragging the selection through 85,000 values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Excel on Windows, I believe one way to do is to hit CTRL + G to open the "Go To" window, then specify your range (1:85000, for example) in the reference box, and hit 'OK'. That should highlight the full range, allowing you to right-click and delete the rows, or just hit 'Delete' to clear them (without shifting).

EDIT: Found a superuser post going over something similar - [Deleting specific rows/columns from excel](https://superuser.com/questions/997804/deleting-specific-rows-columns-from-excel)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a Mac and it still works perfectly!

Comment: @korbman thank you its made my life easy

Answer (score 4):

To select the group: In the top left near the function box, type A1:A85000
[image: selection]

Right click a cell within the selection > click delete... > select entire row

Alternatively: In excel VBA, you can run this to delete the rows:

```
range("A1","A85000").EntireRow.Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the dragging, I usually select the row of one of the endpoints of the range then scroll to the other endpoint and while holding `SHIFT`, select it. With large datasets I find this to be a helpful approach because it's faster than dragging, but it also lets me evaluate whether the range is correct.

While the other answers are more efficient, you are unable to verify that you selected the correct range because you do not necessarily see both endpoints. Scroll/shift adds a validation element to the process.